# Serve media on localhost (windows)

Tags: django, windows

I have an img file which i copied to the /mediafiles/ folder.  How can I display it?  It just returns 404 (not found).  Or is that not possible in DEBUG mode?

I've also tried using `{{ MEDIA_URL }}img1.jpg` in the template but to no avail.
FYI, I have no problems with static images or stylesheets (as long as I don't forget to run collectstatic).

Django 1.8.3, localhost on Windows, in a virtualenv.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

myproject\myapp\settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS= (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/myapp/theme_one'),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/myapp/theme_one'),
) 
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

myproject\myapp\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url  
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^book/', 'book.views.protopage', name='protopage'),
)
```

myproject\book\views.py:

```
def protopage(request):
    picurl = settings.MEDIA_URL + 'img1.jpg'

    return render_to_response('book/protopage.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

myproject\book\templates\book\protopage.html:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><link href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
    <img src='{{ picurl }}'/>
</body>
</html>
```

File structure

```
MYPROJECT
│   .gitignore
│   manage.py
├───book
│       views.py    
├───myapp
│       settings.py
│       urls.py
├───mediafiles
│       img1.jpg
├───static
│   └───myapp
│       └───theme_one
│           ├───css
│           │       style.css
│           └───img
│                   logo.png 
├───staticfiles
├───templates
│   └───myapp
│       └───theme_one
│           └───book
│               └───protopage.html
└───venv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work after reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/

In my urls.py file I need to add the static.serve() view:

```
    from django.conf import settings    
    . . . 
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^book/', 'book.views.protopage', name='protopage'),
        (r'^mediafiles/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT 
        }),
    )
```